# jquery auto complete with multiple parameters in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocomplete, drop-down-menu, url-parameters

I use JSP, I want to pass two parameters along with the jquery auto-complete. My second parameter is value of a select box. I have used the following code but am only getting the first value in the options. i checked the function which returns the select box value, its only get invoked at the page loading. Is there any way to solve my problem?

```
 /* inside my page */


        jQuery(function() {
    $("#branch").autocomplete("getbranchdetails.jsp", {
        extraParams: {
            filter: getDropdownValue()
        }
    });
});


    function getDropdownValue() {
    var compId=document.getElementById("company").value;
    return compId;
    }




        /* inside getbranchdetails.jsp */

        <%
        String company=request.getParameter("filter");

        System.out.println("company :"+company);


        getbranchdetails db=new getbranchdetails();
        String query = request.getParameter("q");
        List<String> agent = db.getData(query,brtype);
        Iterator<String> iterator = agent.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String agents = (String)iterator.next();
        out.println(agents);
        }
        %>
```

i tried the following link too but no luck
http://123code.blogspot.in/2010/09/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("#branch").autocomplete("getbranchdetails.jsp");
extraParams: {
    filter: getDropdownValue()
}
});
```

to

```
$("#branch").autocomplete("getbranchdetails.jsp", {
    extraParams: {
        filter: getDropdownValue()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Schultheiss, that was my mistake when i typed it here. I have edited it now in the question.

Comment: @arjuncc - your question does NOT currently reflect that statement with the extra parenthesis.

Comment: No, your question still has: `"getbranchdetails.jsp"),{ ` see that closing parenthesis, just before that comma? COPY the exact code from my answer and try it.

Comment: see this fiddle with both code snips, click the jslint button to see the errors. http://jsfiddle.net/fZwyK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/PTeMy/

In the autocomplete, the source can be defined as a function call.  Use that and you should be able to build the auto complete list however you want.

For example...

HTML

```
<input id="auto" type="text">

must contain....
<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>        
    <option value="b">b</option>        
    <option value="c">c</option>        
    <option value="d">d</option>        
    <option value="e">e</option>        
    <option value="f">f</option>        
    <option value="g">g</option>        
</select>​
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#auto').autocomplete({
        source: getTags()
    });
});

function getTags(){
        var tags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];   

    tags = $.grep(tags, function(t) {
        return t.indexOf($('select').val()) > 0;
    });

    return tags;
}

​
```

Comment: The OP is using a plug-in, not the jQuery UI autocomplete.

Comment: sorry... missed that.  I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#branch').autocomplete('getbranchdetails.jsp', {
    mustMatch: false
});

$('#branch').setOptions({
    extraParams:{filter: function(){return $('#company').val();}
});
```